# Django: How to return a raw response

Tags: django, response, urllib2

This is what I want.

1. Submit a POST request to a external site(i.e login information).
2. Receive the response
3. Return the raw response to my client's browser(containing the cookies for login
   validation).
4. If the client tries to access the site in new tab  he finds that he is already signed in.

I successfully completed steps 1 & 2 (submitted POST & received the response from the site).

```
request = urllib2.Request(url, formData, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

But when I try to return it in the view

```
return response
```

I get the folllowing error

```
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    addinfourl instance has no attribute 'has_header'
Exception Location:D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\cache.py in patch_vary_headers
```

note:
I had a csrf error previosly,but i disabled csrf using decorator @csrf_exempt & the error was gone

Comment: So in other words you want to perform a man in the middle attack.

Comment: I am an authorized user of the above mentioned external site.I just do not access to their code.

Comment: Understandable. But the principle is the same. If your "solution" involves the same idea as a security exploit, it's probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't return the *response* from urlopen method directly. Instead your view should return an instance of django's [HttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse), where body and the headers should be set to those from the original *response*:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import urllib2

def my_view(request):
    request = urllib2.Request(url, formData, headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

    # set the body
    r = HttpResponse(response.read())

    # set the headers
    for header in response.info().keys():
        r[header] = response.info()[header]

    return r
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it doesn't make sense to submit a URL request as the response in a view. But, even if you could, that wouldn't do what you want. There's no way to log a user in to a different site, for what should be obvious reasons: that would be a massive security hole.